# Mongoose DataTable Record filter with Aggregation Date Range

Tags: datatable, aggregation

I have a problem with combining date range aggregation with, mongoose dataTable plugin.

I have researched all over the internet but nothing, was helpful to solve my problem, My aggregation is working accurately when it's separated, and the DataTable is also filtering the loaded data when the programme is initialized.

And what I am looking for is, to filter Order by `functionDate` Meaning, Please Note `"I want it to be executed from the back end, not the front end so that it can load the requested Orders on the DataTable"`. and my Datatable shows "LOADING" but does not load data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: var sStartDate = moment (req.body.FunctionDate).startOf("week").toDate();
        var sEndDate = moment (req.body.FunctionDate).endOf ("week").add(1,"days").toDate();

Comment: Order.aggregate([{$match: {
        FunctionDate: {$gte:sStartDate,$lt:sEndDate}}}],(function(err,dateresult){
        if  (err){
  
          console.log ("error - " + err);
         // res.end(err);
        } 
        if(dateresult){
         console.log ("Hoof Date - " + JSON.stringify(dateresult));